# Setting Allure Results Directory At Runtime

Tags: java, xml, testng, allure

How do we change file directory in which `Allure xml reports` are generated?

I'd like to change it at run-time.

I'm using java 8 and TestNG.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the following class which contains all Allure properties: https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/blob/master/allure-model/src/main/java/ru/yandex/qatools/allure/config/AllureConfig.java

So the answer is:

```
System.setProperty("allure.results.directory", "path/to/directory");
```

Comment: Value in System.setProperty can only be string. I tried using **System.setProperty("allure.results.directory", "path/to/directory");* which worked

Comment: Fixed this in my answer. You could mark it as correct answer if it works for you.

Comment: Hi, My initial intention for changing result directory was to separate result xml files suite wise. I found that the result goes to correct directory for the first time but when I change system property after it, xml files continue getting published in previous suite folder. I am using java and testng for test cases while I am running it using Jenkins. Do you have any idea why is this happening ?

Comment: Probably this is a bug. Please create respective issue in Github.